# Pidgin missing libnotify plugin on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pidgin, libnotify

I installed pidgin when I upgraded to ubuntu 20.04, and realized immediately that notifications were not working properly and I could not close the buddy list without also closing the chat window.

When I went to check on the libnotify plugin, I realized it was no longer on the list, how can I add it again? I can't seem to find a download link to the standalone plugin anywhere.

Comment: Bug created: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pidgin-libnotify/+bug/1903788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to download the deb package for 18.04 from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/pidgin-libnotify and I installed it into 20.04 with:

```
sudo apt install ./pidgin-libnotify_0.14-9ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: That worked for me, thank you very much! I could not find any other plugin package by Ubuntu that would provide that basic functionality, even after I installed pidgin-plugin-pack. Very disappointing that Ubuntu removed pidgin-libnotify but didn't package any alternative!

Comment: Wasn't expecting an answer this late after six months but it sure worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The libnotify plugin used to be bundled by the Ubuntu pidgin package (even though it is not part of pidgin), however there are other notification plugins (including a more-advanced libnotify++ plugin) on https://pidgin.im/plugins .

Comment: but it does list libnotify as a depencency that's why I didn't install it yet

Comment: @metichi "it" being Pidgin or the libnotify++ plugin?

Comment: purple-libnotify+ , which is the plugin that shows up on the search when typing 'libnotify', lists libnotify as a dependency https://github.com/sardemff7/purple-libnotify-plus#purple-libnotify/

Comment: @metichi yup thats correct, the libnotify+ plugin uses the libnotify system to display notifications, the same as the old libnotify (without a +) plugin (which also uses libnotify) that Ubuntu shipped with their Pidgin package